# react native subscription error: {message: "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"}

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

[image]I don't know why subscription pop up this {message: "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"}. To access subscriotion on graphql playground just fine. But it ended with problems on react native. And it also didn't give me enough information to figure out which part goes wrong. It only gives split undefined. Split undefined is a error log from  tag.

Here is the clent set up

```
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  split
} from "apollo-client-preset";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import apolloLogger from "apollo-link-logger";
import { getMainDefinition } from "apollo-utilities";
import {
  createHttpLink,
  cache,
  errorLink,
  authLink,
  tokenRefreshLink,
  createSubscriptionLink
} from "./links";
import { resolvers, typeDefs } from "./resolvers";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";

let host = "http://localhost:4000";
let mediaHost = "http://localhost:2999";
let subscriptionHost = "ws://localhost:4000";

// Default http link for Queries / Mutations
const defaultLink = createHttpLink(host);

// HTTP Link for Upload mutations
const mediaLink = createUploadLink({ uri: mediaHost });

// Websocket / subscription link
const subscriptionLink = createSubscriptionLink(subscriptionHost);

const httpLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    const operationName = definition.name.value;
    const uploadMutationNames = ["uploadRawUserImage"];
    return (
      definition.operation === "mutation" &&
      uploadMutationNames.includes(operationName)
    );
  },
  mediaLink,
  defaultLink
);

const transportLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  subscriptionLink,
  httpLink
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    split(op => !op.getContext().doNotLog, apolloLogger),
    errorLink,
    authLink,
    errorLink,
    tokenRefreshLink,
    transportLink
  ]),
  resolvers,
  typeDefs
});

let timezone;
try {
  timezone = DeviceInfo.getTimezone();
} catch (e) {
  timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
}
moment.tz.setDefault(timezone);

let weekStart = moment(
  moment(new Date(), null, timezone)
    .startOf("day")
    .utc(),
  moment.ISO_8601
).format();

let weekEnd = moment(
  moment(new Date(), null, timezone)
    .add(1, "w")
    .endOf("day")
    .utc(),
  moment.ISO_8601
).format();

cache.writeData({
  data: {
    userGender: "",
    eventCreation: {
      selectedUserId: null,
      selectedVenueId: null,
      dateTime: null,
      __typename: "EventCreation"
    },
    userDiscoveryFilters: {
      genders: ["MALE", "FEMALE"],
      age: {
        min: 18,
        max: 75,
        __typename: "AgeRange"
      },
      __typename: "UserDiscoveryFilters"
    },
    eventFeed: {
      displayOptions: {
        orderBy: "Date",
        startOfWeek: weekStart,
        endOfWeek: weekEnd,
        selectedDate: moment(new Date()).date(),
        __typename: "EventFeedDisplayOptions"
      },
      viewedEventId: null,
      __typename: "EventFeed"
    },
    eventsOrder: {
      orderBy: "Date",
      __typename: "EventsOrder"
    },
    temporaryOnboardingData: {
      email: null,
      phone: null,
      __typename: "TemporaryOnboardingData"
    },
    permissions: [{ name: "location", value: true, __typename: "Permission" }],
    isSwipeable: true
  }
});

export default client;
```

```
// import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "apollo-client-preset";

const createHttpLink = (host, fetch) => new HttpLink({ uri: host, fetch });

export default createHttpLink;
```

```
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import { SubscriptionClient } from "subscriptions-transport-ws";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const createSubscriptionLink = uri => {
  const subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(uri, {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: () => ({
      authorization: `Bearer ${AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`
    })
  });

  subscriptionClient.connectionCallback = err => {
    if (err.message === "Authentication Failure!") {
      subscriptionClient.close();
    }
  };

  return new WebSocketLink(subscriptionClient);
};
```

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "apollo-client-preset";

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      venue: (_, { where: { id } }, { getCacheKey }) =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: "Venue", id: id }),
      event: (_, { where: { id } }, { getCacheKey }) =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: "Event", id: id }),
      user: (_, { where: { id } }, { getCacheKey }) =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: "User", id: id })
    }
  }
});
export default cache;
```

Here is where I call subscription

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Subscription
        subscription={gql`
          subscription {
            Preselection {
              node {
                id
                selected {
                  id
                }
              }
              mutation
            }
          }
        `}
        context={{ doNotLog: false }}
      >
        {({ data, loading, error }) => {
          if (loading) {
            return <Text>{"Loading..."}</Text>;
          }
          if (error) {
            console.log("PRESELECTION_SUBSCRIPTION error:", error);
            return <Text>{"Error..."}</Text>;
          }

          return <Text>{"PRESELECTION_SUBSCRIPTION"}</Text>;
        }}
      </Subscription>
    );
  }
```

And the error message on browser console as follows:
PRESELECTION_SUBSCRIPTION error: {message: "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"}